# Android List assignment

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, listview

i have a number of text views that i added to list object and i want to initialize them programtically. How do i do this? Is list the best object

My Code so far. View objects added to list.

```
mTextViewList = new ArrayList<TextView>();
        mTextViewList.addAll(Arrays.asList(mTextViewA, mTextViewB, mTextViewC, mTextViewD ));
        String TAG_ID= "id";
```

This is what i am trying to do

```
//Single line assignment works.

 mTextViewA = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("textViewA",TAG_ID, getPackageName()));
 mTextViewB = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("textViewB",TAG_ID, getPackageName()));
```

This doesnt work when objects added to list and used in loop

```
//Forloop doesnt work
        for (int i=0; i<mTextViewList.size(); i++) {

            //System.out.println(list.get(i));
            mTextViewList.get(i) = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("textViewName",TAG_ID, getPackageName()));
        }
```

Comment: Your loop code doesn't make sense. Show what you're trying to do without the loop so we can try to help.

Comment: i am trying to assign a resource to a textview. E.g the single line assignment works above. But if added to a list object and used in forloop it does not work

Comment: The single line assignment makes sense, but the loop doesn't. You can't assign a value to a method. Please show what your code would look like if you specified each step instead of looping.

Comment: Code is now split out. How do i assign values to each object in list ?

Answer (score 0):

The following would make more sense:

```
mTextViewList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < mTextViewList.size(); i++) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("textViewName", TAG_ID, getPackageName()));
    mTextViewList.add(textView);
}
```

Comment: But this will end up with each var in the list named textView? I have each textView named after different views in my xml file.

Comment: You don't store variables in the List, you store objects. If you want to have a variable for each TextView, you'll have to findViewById() manually for each ID.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set a list of items to `TextView`s with names ending in sequential letters. Let's try this:

```
mTextViewList = new ArrayList<>();
int viewCount = ???; // not sure how many elements you have
for (int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) {
    String name = "textView" + (char)('A' + i);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(name, TAG_ID, getPackageName()));
    mTextViewList.add(textView);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately the sequential letters were only an example. I may just have to type them all out individually and initialize

Comment: @user2202098 If they're all custom named, looping isn't really going to work for you. Looping only works when there's some pattern to follow.

Comment: ah so the list object wont have its variable name stored? I just needed it to loop from 0 to x and grab the name of each textView and find the xml resource with same name to initialize